# Is an element of the tangent bundle also an element of the tangent space to a point on the base space?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm a little confused about definitions here. From what I understand, the tangent bundle is the disjoint union of all tangent spaces of the base space. From the definition of a union, the union of two sets is the set containing all the elements of those two sets. This can be expanded to include more than two sets in the usual way. This implies to me that the tangent bundle is the set containing all the elements of all tangent spaces of the base space.

My confusion comes from the fact that if an element of the tangent bundle is simply an element of a tangent space why isn't the dimension of the tangent bundle the same as the dimension of the tangent space if they contain all the same elements? Can a single vector be an element of two different spaces with different dimension?

Answer (score 1):

For each $v \in TM$, there is a unique $p \in M$ such that $v \in T_pM$.

As for your comment about dimension, why would you expect that $\dim TM = \dim T_pM$? Note that $\mathbb{R}^2 = \bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{R}}\{a\}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\dim(\{a\}\times\mathbb{R}) = 1$, but $\dim\mathbb{R}^2 \neq 1$.

Comment: I think my intuition wants to assign the vector itself a dimension rather than the space. I suspected that this was wrong, but wanted confirmation. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. A manifold (in particular, a real vector space) has a dimension, a vector doesn't.